# SOAP requests in .NET

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, exception

We're trying to use SOAP requests to interact with a booking API using Visual Studio C#.

We've interfaced with a Web Service of another API without issue but this one is proving problematic.

We've added it as a Service Reference and Visual Studio has generated all the classes for it and web.config entries so that all seems well.

However when we try and make a simple request to the client SOAP Service we get the following error:

> Namespace='com.hrs.soap.hrs' is not supported with rpc\literal SOAP. The wrapper element has to be unqualified.

The code is:

```
PingRequest pingrequest = new PingRequest();    
SoapServiceClient service = new SoapServiceClient();
service.ping(pingrequest);
```

This what's been added in the Web.config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="HRSSoapServiceBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="..."
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HRSSoapServiceBinding"
          contract="HRSService.HRSSoapService" name="HRSSoapServicePort" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

According to the documentation the request should look like the following:

```
<complexType name="PingRequest">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="tns:Request">
            <sequence>
                <element name="echoData" type="xsd:string"/>
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

Full Stack Trace below:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Namespace='com.hrs.soap.hrs' is not supported with rpc\literal SOAP. The wrapper element has to be unqualified.]
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.CheckTopLevelAttributes(XmlAttributes a, String accessorName) +842469
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportAccessorMapping(MemberMapping accessor, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, Type choiceIdentifierType, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) +4072651
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMemberMapping(XmlReflectionMember xmlReflectionMember, String ns, XmlReflectionMember[] xmlReflectionMembers, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) +699
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMembersMapping(XmlReflectionMember[] xmlReflectionMembers, String ns, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) +298

[InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting 'HRSException'.]
  System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMembersMapping(XmlReflectionMember[] xmlReflectionMembers, String ns, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) +1051
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMembersMapping(String elementName, String ns, XmlReflectionMember[] members, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, XmlMappingAccess access) +137
   System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerImporter.ImportMembersMapping(XmlName elementName, String ns, XmlReflectionMember[] members, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean isEncoded, String mappingKey) +237
   System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationReflector.ImportMembersMapping(String elementName, String ns, XmlReflectionMember[] members, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, String mappingKey) +134
   System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationReflector.ImportFaultElement(FaultDescription fault, XmlQualifiedName& elementName) +458
   System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationReflector.GenerateXmlSerializerFaultContractInfos() +153
   System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationReflector.EnsureMessageInfos() +929
   System.ServiceModel.Description.Reflector.EnsureMessageInfos() +98
   System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.CreateFormatter() +32
   System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.System.ServiceModel.Description.IOperationBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription description, ClientOperation proxy) +42
   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.BindOperations(ContractDescription contract, ClientRuntime proxy, DispatchRuntime dispatch) +94
   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime) +247
   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.BuildProxyBehavior(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, BindingParameterCollection& parameters) +342
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.BuildChannelFactory(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, Boolean useActiveAutoClose) +85
   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.CreateFactory() +43
   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.OnOpening() +23
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +274
   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.EnsureOpened() +107
   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1.CreateChannel(EndpointAddress address, Uri via) +134
   System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1.CreateChannel() +29
   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannel() +91
   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelInternal() +26
   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.get_Channel() +261
   BLL.HRSService.HRSSoapServiceClient.ping(HRSPingRequest pingRequest) in C:\Code\-------\BLL\Service References\HRSService\Reference.cs:15850
   -------.Test.Ping() in C:\Code\-------\Test.aspx.cs:48
   -------.Test.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Code\-------\Test.aspx.cs:24
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

We installed Fiddler and there is no XML request going through that we can see, presumably because it throws an exception before anything is sent.

What exactly do we need to change in our setup to make this work?

**UPDATE**

**WSDL:** Available [here][1]

**UPDATE**

Following davidfmatheson's excellent advice I've copied the WSDL locally and made the amendments as suggested. I'm still getting the same error although possibly in a different place:

```
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        BLL.HRSService.pingResponse BLL.HRSService.HRSSoapService.ping(BLL.HRSService.pingRequest request) {
            return base.Channel.ping(request);
        }

        public BLL.HRSService.HRSPingResponse ping(BLL.HRSService.HRSPingRequestWrapper ping1) {
            BLL.HRSService.pingRequest inValue = new BLL.HRSService.pingRequest();
            inValue.ping = ping1;
            BLL.HRSService.pingResponse retVal = ((BLL.HRSService.HRSSoapService)(this)).ping(inValue);
            return retVal.pingResponse1;
        }
```

The line that fails is the *return base.Channel.ping(request);* with error *Namespace='com.hrs.soap.hrs' is not supported with rpc\literal SOAP. The wrapper element has to be unqualified.*

I also tried to explicitly set the SOAPBinding:

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Namespace='com.hrs.soap.hrs' is not supported with rpc\literal SOAP. The wrapper element has to be unqualified.

Source Error: 

Line 15917:        [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethod(Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal)]
Line 15918:        BLL.HRSService.pingResponse BLL.HRSService.HRSSoapService.ping(BLL.HRSService.pingRequest request) {
Line 15919:            return base.Channel.ping(request);
Line 15920:        }
Line 15921:
```

OK now I've amended the SOAP Binding style to document in my local WSDL and recreated the classes and I have a different error:

```
Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'BLL.HRSService.HRSHotelTaxDetail[]' to 'BLL.HRSService.HRSHotelTaxDetail'
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'BLL.HRSService.HRSHotelAmenityCriterion[]' to 'BLL.HRSService.HRSHotelAmenityCriterion'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'BLL.HRSService.HRSHotelTaxDetail' to 'BLL.HRSService.HRSHotelTaxDetail[]'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'BLL.HRSService.HRSHotelAmenityCriterion' to 'BLL.HRSService.HRSHotelAmenityCriterion[]'
```

**StackTrace:**

```
[InvalidOperationException: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'BLL.HRSService.HRSHotelTaxDetail[]' to 'BLL.HRSService.HRSHotelTaxDetail'
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'BLL.HRSService.HRSHotelAmenityCriterion[]' to 'BLL.HRSService.HRSHotelAmenityCriterion'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'BLL.HRSService.HRSHotelTaxDetail' to 'BLL.HRSService.HRSHotelTaxDetail[]'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'BLL.HRSService.HRSHotelAmenityCriterion' to 'BLL.HRSService.HRSHotelAmenityCriterion[]'
]
   System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence) +1024
   System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies) +1997
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GetSerializersFromCache(XmlMapping[] mappings, Type type) +772
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.FromMappings(XmlMapping[] mappings, Type type) +4066268
   System.ServiceModel.Description.SerializerGenerationContext.GenerateSerializers() +185
   System.ServiceModel.Description.SerializerGenerationContext.GetSerializer(Int32 handle) +102
   System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageInfo.get_BodySerializer() +17
   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeBody(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object returnValue, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest) +112

[CommunicationException: There was an error in serializing body of message pingRequest: 'Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'BLL.HRSService.HRSHotelTaxDetail[]' to 'BLL.HRSService.HRSHotelTaxDetail'
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'BLL.HRSService.HRSHotelAmenityCriterion[]' to 'BLL.HRSService.HRSHotelAmenityCriterion'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'BLL.HRSService.HRSHotelTaxDetail' to 'BLL.HRSService.HRSHotelTaxDetail[]'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'BLL.HRSService.HRSHotelAmenityCriterion' to 'BLL.HRSService.HRSHotelAmenityCriterion[]'
'.  Please see InnerException for more details.]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +9440287
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +345
   BLL.HRSService.HRSSoapService.ping(pingRequest request) +0
   BLL.HRSService.HRSSoapServiceClient.BLL.HRSService.HRSSoapService.ping(pingRequest request) in C:\Code\...\BLL\Service References\HRSService\Reference.cs:17311
   BLL.HRSService.HRSSoapServiceClient.ping(HRSPingRequestWrapper ping1) in C:\Code\...\BLL\Service References\HRSService\Reference.cs:17317
   BLL.HRS_Integration.Ping() in C:\Code\...\BLL\General\HRSIntegration.cs:55
   VenueOptions.Test.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Code\...\Test.aspx.cs:24
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

Request finally made!

Fiddler shows the following for PING:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><ping xmlns="com.hrs.soap.hrs"><pingRequest xmlns=""><credentials><clientType>...</clientType><clientKey>...</clientKey><clientPassword>...</clientPassword><customerKey xsi:nil="true"/></credentials><myHRSCredentials xsi:nil="true"/><echoData>Hello HRS</echoData></pingRequest></ping></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Check the stack trace and see where your code is cracking up. Is it in the request build faze or the response de-serialization faze?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, Stack Trace added

Comment: Out of curiosity, is wsdl.exe capable of generating a working proxy?

Comment: How did you solve the "error CS0030: Cannot convert type" problem? I'm getting that and it's for a type that's not even references in the method I'm calling!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to consume an RPC-literal service from .NET, so you may have to convert the service to doc-literal.  See [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/beatsch/archive/2004/08/23/218886.aspx).

EDIT: More complete answer

The goal is to be able to use doc-literal, but still send the same message.  Let's focus on the `ping` operation.  Right now your WSDL has the type defined as:

```
<complexType name="HRSPingRequest">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="tns:HRSRequest">
            <sequence>
                <element name="echoData" type="xsd:string"/>
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

And your message defined as:

```
<message name="HRSSoapService_pingRequest">
    <part name="pingRequest" type="tns:HRSPingRequest"/>
</message>
```

And your binding defined as:

```
<binding name="HRSSoapServiceBinding" type="tns:HRSSoapService">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="ping">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <input>
            <soap:body namespace="com.hrs.soap.hrs" use="literal"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body namespace="com.hrs.soap.hrs" use="literal"/>
        </output>
        <fault name="HRSException">
            <soap:fault name="HRSException" use="literal"/>
        </fault>
    </operation>
</binding>
```

So locally we change the "rpc" to "document" and then fix the WSDL to actual document/literal:

```
<element name="ping" type="tns:HRSPingRequestWrapper" />
<complexType name="HRSPingRequestWrapper">
    <sequence>
        <element name="pingRequest" type="tns:HRSPingRequest" />
    </sequence>
</complexType>
<complexType name="HRSPingRequest">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="tns:HRSRequest">
            <sequence>
                <element name="echoData" type="xsd:string"/>
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>

...

<message name="HRSSoapService_pingRequest">
    <part name="pingRequest" element="tns:ping"/>
</message>
```

Now generate off of this WSDL and see if it sends a ping request.  If you don't fix the Response structure, it may not understand what comes back, but you should at least see a request sent out over the wire.  You can use SoapUI to load both WSDLs and see what kind of requests are generated.  The goal is to send the same request, just using document/literal instead of rpc/literal.

Comment: Thanks for the link, we'll have a good look through. No we don't have control of the web service producer. It all seems more complicated than it should be.

Comment: We can't convert the service to doc-literal as we have no control of the service itself. We've tried adding [SoapRpcService(Use = SoapBindingUse.Literal)] to all the auto generated classes but we just get the same error.

Comment: I think that blog entry is talking about taking just the WSDL and schema from the service, saving it locally, modifying it as described, generating stubs off of that modified local WSDL, then still pointing the client at the original endpoint address.  It is an old blog post, and I have never tried exactly that, but I think that's what they're suggesting.

Comment: Can you post the WSDL and schema of the service?

Comment: You could also try marking the `ping [WebMethod]` with `[ SoapRpcService(Use = SoapBindingUse.Encoded) ]` (also `.Default`), or also `[ SoapDocumentMethod(Use=SoapBindingUse.Encoded) ]`

Comment: How to I access the WSDL and schema of the service? Also, we're not calling the ping from a WebMethod but just from a Form Load event

Comment: You should be able to get it from `http://iut-service.hrs.com:8080/service/hrs/019/HRSService?wsdl`.  If the WSDL has an imported schema, then grab that too and post it.

Comment: Question updated with the WSDL and imported schema. Appreciate the help

Comment: Edited answer with example for your WSDL.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I've put a copy of the WSDL locally, made the amendments you suggested and re-added the Service Reference. I had to change my PingRequest code to create a PingWrapper and assign the PingRequest to that. It all built OK but when I run it I still get the same error, see my updated question

Comment: It looks like .NET is still trying to go rpc/literal.  Try forcing the ping request to `[ SoapDocumentMethod(Use=SoapBindingUse.Literal) ]`.  Right now your goal is to just see the request go out from your client using WireShark or Fiddler.

Comment: Did you change `<soap:binding style="rpc"` to `<soap:binding style="document"` in your local WSDL?  Not sure why it's still trying to use rpc.

Comment: Doh I didn't realise I needed to change that! Different error now :)

Comment: Is it sending a request out, though?  Have you checked in Fiddler whether it's actually shipping off some XML?

Comment: No it doesn't look like it, it 500's before the request is made

Comment: Evidently this is a different issue, and one that others encounter.  See http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2010/02/net-wcf-bug-cannot-convert-type-to.html for a good solution.  Add the author's `<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="dummyFriend" type="xsd:string"/>` to the type definition for `HRSHotelTax`.  Make sure this gets rid of the `HRSHotelTaxDetail[]` problem, then repeat for the other types.

Comment: Hallelujah!  Fiddler shows the request! Thanks so much for your help :)  Do I now need to go through and amend every single definition in this 3000+ line WSDL?

Comment: The response that is being received from the ping is coming back as null, I assume that's because the format is now incorrect. How would I go about converting it? Presumably the response is now coming back in rpc/literal but it's expected to be unqualified?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15074/discussion-between-davidfmatheson-and-cusimar9)

Comment: @davidfmatheson Please refrain from asking for accept marks, they are considered noise and should not be made.  Failing to do so may incur future moderator action.

Comment: @casperOne Will do (or rather, not do).  I'm relatively new, thanks for the tip.