# Namespace is not supported with rpc\\literal SOAP. The wrapper element has to be unqualified

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently working on an integration with a leasing service provider, which runs (I assume) a Java service.

When I add the service reference in Visual Studio 2012, the reference is created correctly and I can call the methods specified in the service.

The problem arises when I get a response from the service.

Let's say I call the service with wrong parameters `getCalculation` and I get the JSON response `JSONException`. The problem is, that Visual Studio throws an exception `There was an error reflecting 'JSONException'.` and as InnerException: `{"Namespace='http://service.ecommerce.cetelem.hu/' is not supported with rpc\\literal SOAP. The wrapper element has to be unqualified."}`

This is the web.config code:

```
<system.serviceModel>  
    <bindings>  
        <basicHttpBinding>  
            <binding name="EcommerceServiceImplPortBinding">  
                <security mode="Transport" />  
            </binding>  
            <binding name="EcommerceServiceImplPortBinding1" />  
        </basicHttpBinding>  
    </bindings>  
    <client>  
        <endpoint address="https://ecomdemo.cetelem.hu:443/ecommerce/EcommerceService"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="EcommerceServiceImplPortBinding"
          contract="CetelemInstallmentsService.EcommerceService" name="EcommerceServiceImplPort" />  
    </client>  
</system.serviceModel>
```

If this is of any help, I'm using `WebAPI` for the user "front-end".

Thank you for all the answers!

Comment: could not understand if this is a json or xml service. for json - might want to use web api or just send raw json. for xml - you could use .net 2 web services by using "add web reference" instead of "add service reference"

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The problem is, that the service is defined with a WSDL, but it returns JSON.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured this thing out eventually, but with the help of another post on SO: [SOAP Requests in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796076/soap-requests-in-net)

All I needed to change in the service refence file was:

```
[System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style = System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, SupportFaults = true)]
```

To:

```
[System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style = System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Document, SupportFaults = true)]
```

Comment: The service reference file name is Reference.cs.

Comment: also the refernece file is hidden in visual studio solution explorer unless "show all files" is selected

Comment: When i do this, i lose the ability to read any response that is returned.

Comment: @ChrisRice: Have you fixed this issue?

Comment: No, i found an alternative i think.