# There was an error reflecting 'IOException' while consuming javawebservice in my mvc application

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, webforms

I am trying to consume a java web service in my mvc application but its throwing `IOException`, `InvalidOperationException`.

Here is my code:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string name = txtUserName.Text + "@abc.com";

        LoginService.SimpleLDAPAuthenticationClient objAuthendication = new SimpleLDAPAuthenticationClient();
        var isvalid = objAuthendication.isAuthenticated(name, txtPassword.Text);

        Response.Redirect(isvalid ? "/LoginSuccess.aspx" : "/error.html");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
                Response.Redirect("/error.html");
    }
}
```

and my config file is:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SimpleLDAPAuthenticationImplPortBinding" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://devserver:8080/doi/authenticate"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SimpleLDAPAuthenticationImplPortBinding"
        contract="LoginService.SimpleLDAPAuthentication" name="SimpleLDAPAuthenticationImplPort" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Full exception is

```
Namespace="//example.com/" is not supported  with rpc\literal soap. The wrapper element has to be unqualified.
```

Any help please?

Comment: This doesn't look like MVC to me..

Comment: @testydonkey true, that doesn't look like a MVC. On what line on your code the exception is? Could yo provide a complete exception?

Comment: Seems to be a WCF issue ? is anonymous acces to this webservice allowed ?

Comment: im sorry i copied sample asp.net application code. the exception is while authendicating in isauthendicated.

Comment: i have modified the exception in detail

Comment: could be an encoding issue according to this post :[soap-requests-in-net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796076/soap-requests-in-net)